# How can I make it so my while-loop only prints even numbers? Java Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement, while-loop

Beginner here. For my coding class, we have an assignment that requires us to print numbers 1-20, but configure it so that it only outputs even numbers. Here is what I have so far but I'm quite stuck. He says to put an if statement and use the "%" operator but I've no idea where to put them.

```
    int counter = 1;
    System.out.println("Part 2 - Even Numbers");
    while (counter <= 20)
    {
        //if (counter 
        System.out.printf("%d ", counter);
        counter++;
    } // end while loop
```

[Instructions for assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2QLJ.png)

[My Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qIpx.png)

[CORRECT Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXjFC.png)

Comment: To me, adding an if statement seems like adding unnecessary complication.  Why not just make the while loop condition go to 10, instead of 20, and print out counter times 2 each time?

Comment: As you only want to print some of the numbers, the if statement will need to go around the print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**%** is an arithmetic operator, it is called [MODULO](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modulo-or-remainder-operator-in-java/).
Modulo operator returns the remainder of 2 numbers. In this case, we use a modulo to find out whether a number is even or odd.

**odd%2** returns **1**

**even%2** returns **0**

The while loop loops through the first 20 elements. So we put an if statement before printing the element. If the counter is an even number i.e (counter%2 == 0) we print that.

This is the code that prints even numbers:

```
        int counter = 0;
        System.out.println("Part 2 - Even Numbers");
        while (counter <= 20)
        {
            if (counter%2 == 0){
                System.out.printf("%d ", counter);
            }
            counter++;
        } // end while loop
```

This can also be done without using MODULO operator:

```
        int counter = 0;
        System.out.println("Part 2 - Even Numbers");
        while (counter <= 20)
        {
            System.out.printf("%d ", counter);
            counter+=2;
        } // end while loop
```

Comment: Small correction: In Java, the `%` operator is the [remainder operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3) - not the modulo operator. Some languages handle `%` (or `mod`) [differently from others](https://torstencurdt.com/tech/posts/modulo-of-negative-numbers/).

Answer (score 2):

```
  if(counter % 2 == 0){
      System.out.printf("%d ", counter);
  }
  counter++;
```

**%** operator is mod operator, if **counter % 2 == 0** , then counter is an even number

Answer (score 0):

use fori

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

% is the remainder operation